# Arangodb - slow cursors

Tags: arangodb, aql

Hi I've got a simple collection with 40k records in. It's just an import of a csv (c.4Mb) so it has a consistent object per document and is for an Open Data portal.

I need to be able to offer a full download of the data as well as the capabilities of AQL for querying, grouping, aggregating etc.

If I set batchSize to the full dataset then it takes around 50 seconds to return and is unsurprisingly about 12Mb due to the column names.
eg 
`{"query":"for x in dataset return x","batchSize":50000}`

I've tried things caching and balancing between a larger batchSize and using the cursor to build the whole dataset but I can't get the response time down very much.

Today I came across the `attributes` and `values` functions and created this AQL statement.

`{"query":"return union(
for x in dataset limit 1 return attributes(x,true),
for x in dataset return values(x,true))","batchSize":50000}`

It will mean I have to unparse the object but I use [PapaParse](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#json-to-csv) so that should be no issue (not proved yet).

Is this the best / only way to have an option to output the full csv and still have a response that performs well?

I am trying to avoid having to store the data multiple times, eg once raw csv then data in a collection. I guess there may be a dataset that is too big to cope with this approach but this is one of our bigger datasets.

Thanks

Comment: So you query the database and construct the CSV yourself? How about using arangoexport instead? Otherwise you might be interested in streaming queries, which is available in devel and will be shipped in the upcoming 3.4 version: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/4769

Comment: Great thanks. Yes one option was to form the CSV myself as I can't get it straight out of the database (I accept it's perhaps not a common requirement). Looks like I need to look at PapaParse, client side it unparses in a couple of seconds, server side it takes about 17 seconds. The _api/cursor call is very fast now even when returning c.40k resords. I'll look at the arangoexport as I may just have a batch job to create the csv's over night as the data isn't dynamic during the day. I'll also take a look at streaming queries. Thanks...

Comment: What exactly are these special requirements about the CSV format? Does it have to do with escaping? Or is it about the output order? Arangoexport does have a query option which can be used to restructure and sort the data if that is what you are after.

Comment: Hi @CoDEmanX, thanks, I've not got any special requirements. I have a web application so I'd prefer to pass csv without having to go through to command line Arangoexport. I will if it proves to be faster though.